# Trying to validate the username already exists going wrong Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, validation, registration

I am trying to validate that a user already exists but I'm having trouble with it.

This is the function to create a user

```
protected function storeCliente(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:40|',
            'surname' => 'required|max:40|',
            'cedula' => 'required|digits:10|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'telefono' => 'required|between:9,15',
            'direccion' => 'required',
            'ciudadResi' => 'required',
            'fechaNacimiento' => 'required',
            'genero' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'name.max' =>"El nombre de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'surname.max' =>"El apellido de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'cedula.digits' =>"La cédula tiene que tener 10 caracteres",
            'cedula.numeric' =>"La cédula tiene que ser numérica",
            'telefono.between' =>"El número de teléfono tiene que tener entre 9 y 15 caracteres",
            'email.unique' =>"Ya existe un usuario con ese correo electrónico"
        ]);
        
        $a= 'C'.$request['cedula'];
        if(User::where('name',$a)){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Un usuario con ese nombre ya existe, revise la cédula y el rol']);
        }

        $cliente= Persona::create([
            'nombre' => $request['name'],
            'apellido' => $request['surname'],
            'cedula' => $request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'telefono' =>$request['telefono'],
            'direccion' =>$request['direccion'],
            'ciudadResi' =>$request['ciudadResi'],
            'fechaNacimiento' =>$request['fechaNacimiento'],
            'genero' =>$request['genero'],
            'estado'=> '1',
            'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
        ]);
        $usuario= User::create([
            'name' => 'C'.$request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make('C'.$request['cedula']),
            'role' => 'cliente',
            'idPersona'=> $cliente->id,
            'estado' => 2
        ]);
        $mensaje = 'Se creó el cliente '.$cliente->nombre.' '.$cliente->apellido.' con usuario '. $usuario->name;
        return redirect()->route('home',['mensaje'=>$mensaje]);
    }
```

As you can see I create a `persona` and the user is created based on the field `cedula` that comes from a form input following this logic. `'C'.$request['cedula']`

I'm trying to check if the username already exists and if it already does redirect to the form and report the error with the code below.

```
$a= 'C'.$request['cedula'];
            if(User::where('name',$a)){
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Un usuario con ese nombre ya existe, revise la cédula y el rol']);
            }
```

But with that code even when the field `name` would be unique it doesn't allow me to register it.

Gonna show the structure of each table.

Users table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPersona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 31,
  `prueba` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_FK` (`idPersona`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Personas table

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ciudadResi` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fechaNacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `genero` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `estado` binary(1) NOT NULL,
  `idTipoPersona` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idPersona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `personas_FK` (`idTipoPersona`),
  KEY `personas_FK_1` (`idPersona`),
  CONSTRAINT `personas_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idTipoPersona`) REFERENCES `tipo_personas` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `personas_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

If I'm not making myself clear I can edit the question to try to explain myself better.
In summary what I'm trying to do is that before adding to the database the persona and the user it checks if the username that would be made of `'C'.$request['cedula']` already exists, and if it does redirect back to the form showing the error.

Edit This is how I have my function after Robert suggestion with the error `Class "App\Http\Controllers\Rule" not found`

```
protected function storeCliente(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:40|',
            'surname' => 'required|max:40|',
            'cedula' => [
                'required',
                'digits:10',
                'numeric',
                Rule::unique('users', 'name')
                    ->where('name', 'C' . $request['cedula'])
            ],
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'telefono' => 'required|between:9,15',
            'direccion' => 'required',
            'ciudadResi' => 'required',
            'fechaNacimiento' => 'required',
            'genero' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'name.max' =>"El nombre de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'surname.max' =>"El apellido de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'cedula.digits' =>"La cédula tiene que tener 10 caracteres",
            'cedula.numeric' =>"La cédula tiene que ser numérica",
            'cedula.unique' => "Un usuario con ese nombre ya existe, revise la cédula y el rol",
            'telefono.between' =>"El número de teléfono tiene que tener entre 9 y 15 caracteres",
            'email.unique' =>"Ya existe un usuario con ese correo electrónico"
        ]);
        
        
        $cliente= Persona::create([
            'nombre' => $request['name'],
            'apellido' => $request['surname'],
            'cedula' => $request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'telefono' =>$request['telefono'],
            'direccion' =>$request['direccion'],
            'ciudadResi' =>$request['ciudadResi'],
            'fechaNacimiento' =>$request['fechaNacimiento'],
            'genero' =>$request['genero'],
            'estado'=> '1',
            'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
        ]);
        $usuario= User::create([
            'name' => 'C'.$request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make('C'.$request['cedula']),
            'role' => 'cliente',
            'idPersona'=> $cliente->id,
            'estado' => 2
        ]);
        $mensaje = 'Se creó el cliente '.$cliente->nombre.' '.$cliente->apellido.' con usuario '. $usuario->name;
        return redirect()->route('home',['mensaje'=>$mensaje]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fetch the user correctly in your if conditional.

Instead of this

```
if(User::where('name',$a)){
    ....
}
```

Try this

```
if(User::where('name',$a)->first()){
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
protected function storeCliente(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:40|unique:users',
            'surname' => 'required|max:40|',
            'cedula' => 'required|digits:10|numeric',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'telefono' => 'required|between:9,15',
            'direccion' => 'required',
            'ciudadResi' => 'required',
            'fechaNacimiento' => 'required',
            'genero' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'name.max' =>"El nombre de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'surname.max' =>"El apellido de la especialidad no puede ser mayor a 40 caracteres",
            'cedula.digits' =>"La cédula tiene que tener 10 caracteres",
            'cedula.numeric' =>"La cédula tiene que ser numérica",
            'telefono.between' =>"El número de teléfono tiene que tener entre 9 y 15 caracteres",
            'email.unique' =>"Ya existe un usuario con ese correo electrónico"
        ]);
        
        $a= 'C'.$request['cedula'];
        if(User::where('name',$a)){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Un usuario con ese nombre ya existe, revise la cédula y el rol']);
        }

        $cliente= Persona::create([
            'nombre' => $request['name'],
            'apellido' => $request['surname'],
            'cedula' => $request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'telefono' =>$request['telefono'],
            'direccion' =>$request['direccion'],
            'ciudadResi' =>$request['ciudadResi'],
            'fechaNacimiento' =>$request['fechaNacimiento'],
            'genero' =>$request['genero'],
            'estado'=> '1',
            'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
        ]);
        $usuario= User::create([
            'name' => 'C'.$request['cedula'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make('C'.$request['cedula']),
            'role' => 'cliente',
            'idPersona'=> $cliente->id,
            'estado' => 2
        ]);
        $mensaje = 'Se creó el cliente '.$cliente->nombre.' '.$cliente->apellido.' con usuario '. $usuario->name;
        return redirect()->route('home',['mensaje'=>$mensaje]);
    }
```

Comment: Just edit the validation.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not trying to validate a field of the $request, Becuase the name field in User is a combination of a string and the field of $request. Luciano answer works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're trying to validate the user that way? You should be able to just add it as another validation rule. Try something like this (I just copied your error message where you're checking for users with that name and added that return error message as the "cedula.unique" validation error message). The idea would be something like this:

```
$request->validate([
    // ...
    'cedula' => [
        'required',
        'digits:10',
        'numeric',
        Rule::unique('users', 'name')
            ->where('name', 'C' . $request['cedula'])
    ],
],
[
    // ...
    'cedula.unique' =>"'Un usuario con ese nombre ya existe, revise la cédula y el rol'",
]);
```

Comment: So that is also possible, I'm kinda new to Laravel so didn't knew that was possible, gonna try with your way Robert.

Comment: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Rule" not found I get that error even when I try to use your code. Tried using use App\Http\Controllers\Rule; at the start but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because Rule isn't in the Controllers namespace. Add  `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` to the top of your Controller file.